# Como utilizar TopIndex no Delphi FMX?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, listbox

Saudações. No Delphi VCL o ListBox tem a propriedade TopIndex. E no Delphi FMX como usar isso?
Desde já agradeço.

Comment: Tente como diz [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24083766/9559436) `THackListBox(ListBox1).VScrollBar.Value := 0;` não uso Delphi FMX para testar e ter certeza se é isso que precisa, por isso não respondi. Se funcionar, formalizo como resposta

Comment: Não deu certo. Tentei reproduzir mas o Listbox não tem a propriedade VScrollBar.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <seuListBox>.ItemIndex := 0;
```

Comment: Seria interessante explicar o código.